# Calculate $dy/dx$ given that $\sin(2x + 2y) = \sin^2 (x) + \sin^2 (y)$

Tags: derivatives

After differentiating both sides of the equation w.r.t. $x$, this is how far I got:

$$\cos(2x + 2y)\left(2 + 2 \frac{dy}{dx}\right) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) + 2 \sin(y)\cos(y) \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Assuming this is correct, I am not really sure how to isolate dy/dx to obtain the final answer here.

Comment: nice thing about implicit differentiation is that, because of the chain rule, the result always depends linearly on $dy/dx$ so isolating $dy/dx$ is never further than one subtraction and one division away.

Answer (score 1):

From your last line, you can start by distributing the left hand side of the equality to get: $$2\cos(2x+2y) + 2\cos(2x+2y) \frac{dy}{dx}.$$ Move over the terms that have $$dy/dx$$ to one side and solve accordingly. Does that make sense?